# Is draft.js on bower?

Tags: reactjs, bower, draftjs

**I would be really interested in installing draft.js through bower: does the library exist on this package manager? **

It can be installed through npm but this make it hard to install on a rails framework.
thx

Answer (score 3):

Nope.

In its current state, Bower is bad for JS.
It's said Bower is dead (or is nearing it's death). Big names in JS are moving to NPM only.

Several opinions here (comment + whole thread)
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/944#issuecomment-154858804

*Disclaimer: answer is highly opinionated*